# Images not loading on Linode VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn, linode

I deployed my new rails 4 application to linode. 
My js/css are loaded properly but the images are not loading.

Here are my setting in production.rb.

```
  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx
```

## EDIT

So i checked my shared/assets/images
It has the image like `twitter-7ea9292a334406402a4f2e823622fe49.png`

But when I inspect my html it shows

```
<img src="assets/twitter.png">
```

Comment: Could you provide controller and view code for where the image should be rendered?

Comment: `<%= image_tag(image_path("/assets/twitter.png")) %>`

Comment: <img src="/assets/twitter.png" />

Comment: And you're running the app in with RAILS_ENV=production or equivalent?

Comment: Thanks to ole.
Used <%= image_tag 'twitter.png' %> and it worked. Wierd!!

Comment: Does this means we can't use html image tag with the assets pipeline?